# Is there any way to check if socket is alive via ObjectOutputStream or Socket itself?

Tags: java

I wrote a client-server chat room in Java. I want to make sure all the users are online, and if someone has disconnected by fource, I want to tell everyone that he has left.
How can I check if the user is online?
I have a Class with this data: Username, Socket, ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream to each user...
Thanks a-lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the traffic through the port using this. This program I wrote a while back monitors the socket. If you multicast messages to various sockets you can amend this program to give the presense of clients on that port ~

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ConnectionTest {

    private static boolean available(int port) {
        System.out.println("--------------Testing port " + port);
        Socket s = null;
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", port);

            // If the code makes it this far without an exception it means
            // something is using the port and has responded.
            System.out.println("--------------Port " + port + " is not available");
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("--------------Port " + port + " is available");
            return true;
        } finally {
            if( s != null){
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("You should handle this error." , e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println (available (1234)); // check if someone is on the port

    }

}
```

ALSO

---

```
 private void closeLink() {
    try{
        out.println ("bye"); //tell server client is disconnecting
        sock.close ();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println (e);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wish to check if the user is still connected to the server, So I actually can't send connection request to the client from the server....

Comment: OK - David - I wrote a Multicast TCP chat program in java. They way I handled users leaving was that if they pressed the 'x' button on the GUI it would send a 'bye' request through the streams to the server that would remove them from a ChatGroup List.

Comment: I did it already, What I want to do next is if user disconnect by force (don't send 'x' command) the server will know about it. I did it in c++ but in Java it's seems to be much harder :\

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check the `Socket` object. Assuming that your per-user class isn't constructed until the TCP connection actually comes in, just use [`Socket#isClosed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isClosed%28%29). Note also the behavior documented on `getInputStream()`.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help.. I'm trying to send msg to the client to check if he is online but its makes the server stuck.. and the isClosed() method doesn't work - maybe becouse client don't actually close the connection, He makes connection RST.

Comment: If the client goes offline, the TCP connection will drop; that's the point of TCP. If the connection is still alive, the client is still online.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it another chance.. Thanks a-lot :)